# OpenCL : incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing

Tags: c++, opencl

I wrote the following kernel code, but it gave me the following warning. I have tried different solutions but failed. plz any suggestion would help

```
`26:48: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing '__global int' to parameter of type 'int *'
            array_dist[i] = Euclidean_distance(X_train[i],  data_point[j]);
```

my kernel code:

```
 inline float Euclidean_distance(int * array_point_A, int * array_point_B) {
    float sum = 0.0;

    float  w[20] = { 0.0847282, 0.0408621, 0.105036, 0.0619821, 0.0595455, 0.0416739, 0.0181147, 0.00592921,
     0.040049, 0.0766054, 0.0441091, 0.0376111, 0.0124285, 0.0733558, 0.0587338, 0.0303001, 0.0579207, 0.0449221,
          0.0530462, 0.0530462 };

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
        float a = array_point_A[i] - array_point_B[i];
        float wieghted_distance = w[i] * (a * a);
        sum += wieghted_distance;

    }
    return sqrt(sum);
}



__kernel void KNN_classifier(__global  int * restrict X_train, __global  int * restrict Y_train, __global  int * restrict data_point, int k)
{
     
    float array_dist[4344] = {};
    int index_arr[4344] = {};
    for (int i = 0; i < 4344; ++i) { 
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; ++j) {
            array_dist[i] = Euclidean_distance(X_train[i],  data_point[j]);
            index_arr[i] = i;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__global int*` and `int*` for the function parameter (identical to `__private int*`) are different memory spaces. `__global` is video memory and `__private` is registers on the silicon of the GPU die.

To get rid of the warning, in your Euclidean_distance function, make both `array_point_A` and `array_point_B` type `__global int* restrict`. Then the compiler knows that you hand over a pointer to global memory space:

```c
inline float Euclidean_distance(__global int * restrict array_point_A, __global int * restrict array_point_B) {
```

Where you call the function in the kernel, you need to hand over the arrays, not array elements (remove `[i]` and `[j]`, make sure to access the correct elements in the `Euclidean_distance` function):

```c
array_dist[i] = Euclidean_distance(X_train,  data_point);
```

EDIT: I don't exactly understand what you want the code to do.

1. hand over the entire arrays to the function or
2. only hand over array elements to the function

I have written above what is wrong in case of 1.

In case 2: Remove the pointer `*` for the function parameters and in the function access them as variables, not arrays (remove the `[i]`):

```c
inline float Euclidean_distance(int array_point_A, int array_point_B) {
    ...
        float a = array_point_A - array_point_B;
    ...
}
```

Comment: will check and back to you

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but gave me this warining:  "  warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing '__global int' to parameter of type '__global int *'; take the address with & [-Wint-conversion]
            array_dist[i] = Euclidean_distance(X_train[i],data_point[j]);
                                               ^~~~~~~~~~
 "

Comment: Add the `restrict` as well.

Comment: I just add the restrict. and still gave me the same warring " 
:28:48: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing '__global int' to parameter of type '__global int *'; take the address with & [-Wint-conversion]
            array_dist[i] = Euclidean_distance(X_train[i],data_point[j]);
                                               ^~~~~~~~~~"

Comment: [note: passing argument to parameter 'array_point_A' here
inline float Euclidean_distance(__global int* restrict array_point_A,__global int* restrict array_point_B) ]

Comment: Now it gave me errors : " error: subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector
        float a = array_point_A[i] - array_point_B[i];
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
"

Comment: Where you call the function in the kernel, you need to hand over the arrays, not array elements. I just updated my answer again.

Comment: thank you very much for your help, its work correctly for case 1. which is my case